# Cast []struct_instance to []struct

Tags: go

I am struggling to understand and make it work.
I have two structs first:

```
type Directory struct {
    <CONTENT>
}
```

second:

```golang
type Directories []struct {
    Directory
}
```

Now one of my functions returns

```
*[]Directory
```

and second takes an argument:

```
Directories
```

How can I convert

```
*[]Directory -> Directories
```

I think it should be double while Directories is like an abstraction over array/slice of Directory but I may be missing something.

Comment: Because the slice elements have a different type, you will need to write code to do the conversion.  Consider using `type Directories []Directory` or using `[]Directory` directly.

Comment: Thanks first solution is what I needed :)

Comment: You cannot cast types in Go. Go does not have type casting at all. You must perform a type conversion.

Comment: Why do you have `type Directories []struct{ Directory }` rather than `type Directories []Directory`?  It's very odd to embed a struct that way.

Comment: Now I understand that ```type Directories []Directory``` is better, but I am at beginning of learning curve.